# Inconsistent Microsoft Graph Api $count response for users

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, odata, azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to get a total count of users through Microsoft Graph API through my B2C AAD tenant, but the response seems to either error out or is omitting the `@odata.count` property.

Feedback online is also mixed where some people say that `$count` is still unsupported even thought the official documentation says that `$count` is supported for /users.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters#count-parameter

I tried through the graph api online version:
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer?request=users?$count=true&method=GET&version=v1.0

With this result:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users",
    "@odata.count": 31,
    "value": [
    ...
    ]
}
```

However doing the same thing through something like postman nets me this result:

```
GET /v1.0/users?$count=true HTTP/1.1
Host: graph.microsoft.com
Authorization: Bearer [token]
ConsistencyLevel: eventual
```

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "This request is not supported by the service",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2020-10-09T18:19:44",
            "request-id": "4d97fd77-19ad-42f9-9357-66c24c867ce2",
            "client-request-id": "4d97fd77-19ad-42f9-9357-66c24c867ce2"
        }
    }
}
```

If I remove `ConsistencyLevel` header, I get a valid response but there is no `@odata.count` property.

Is there some Graph Api permissions that I am missing, or is this expected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the B2C tenant the user count is not yet supported for this /users endpoint. But for a general Azure AD tenant it will give you the count when you follow these below steps.

1. Select the beta endpoint. (`https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true`)
2. Add $count=true in the QueryString.
3. Add `ConsistencyLevel = eventual` to the Request headers.

You will see the results as below.

[image]

You can also refer this [Document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/blogs/build-advanced-queries-with-count-filter-search-and-orderby/).

Please raise a feature request in the [Microsoft Graph Feedback Forum](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) so that the product team may add this feature to b2c tenant in future.

Comment: The feedback link goes to a 404, would love an updated link so I could vote up or add a new request for adding this feature parity. Switched some existing code to target a B2C tenant and hit this issue today :(