# How do you (quickly) count AAD B2C users?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

We're trying to count the number of user objects in a B2C tenant, which is somewhat large. When it was small, the simple/obvious hack of just reading all the users worked easily and quickly.

```
Get-AzADUser | Measure-Object
```

Now this takes an absurd amount of time (30+ mins, and wastes AAD processing, network bandwidth, etc). Handily, the Graph API includes an endpoint to request the number of objects! Hooray! ;) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#example-6-get-only-a-count-of-users

```
Connect-AzAccount
Set-AzContext -Tenant <your 'normal' AAD tenant>
$AzToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://graph.microsoft.com

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Authentication Bearer -Token (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $AZAccess.Token) -Headers @{ConsistencyLevel = 'eventual'} -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/`$count

1234
```

But! When using this method to attempt to find how many B2C accounts we have:

```
Connect-AzAccount
Set-AzContext -Tenant <your 'B2C' AAD tenant>
$AzToken = Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://graph.microsoft.com

Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Authentication Bearer -Token (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force -String $AZAccess.Token) -Headers @{ConsistencyLevel = 'eventual'} -Uri https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/`$count

Invoke-RestMethod: {"error":{"code":"Request_BadRequest","message":"$count is not currently supported.","innerError":{"date":"2021-04-29T07:06:09","request-id":"xxx","client-request-id":"xxx"}}}
```

So, how do you count users in a large B2C tenant?

Comment: More than a year since this post and according to the MS documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/microsoft-graph-operations this count functionality it still not available.

Wonder what solution you landed on to get a (quick) count on the number of users in Azure AD B2C?

Comment: I still don't have a quick way of doing it. The two main approaches are still either a long-running query where you refresh your access token regularly, or multiple parallel queries for smaller result sets e.g. startswith(objectId, '0') and so on (we use a custom attribute for relying party id, not objectId)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now a somewhat new answer from Microsoft, since June-2023-ish.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/tenant-management-directory-quota

Their page has some instructions to create an application registration, but the most important parts are (paraphrased):

1. For your app to call Microsoft Graph API ... grant Organization.Read.All permission
2. GET 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/organization?$select=directorySizeQuota'
3. The result is a count of all AAD objects; these objects include user accounts, app registrations, groups, etc

Results:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/$metadata#organization(directorySizeQuota)",
    "value": [
        {
            "directorySizeQuota": {
                "used": 211802,
                "total": 50000000
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the endpoint is not supported yet for B2C tenant. Neither does `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$count=true`.

It's only available in normal AAD tenant.

Currently you need to list all the users and get their count using method/function from other library.

A similar post and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64285552/inconsistent-microsoft-graph-api-count-response-for-users?answertab=votes#tab-top) for your reference.

Comment: Hmm. Ok. The all users list currently takes ~90mins, which is not ideal.

Comment: @Froosh It is really frustrating that MS has not yet integrated B2C. You can put forward your needs on user voice.

Comment: Just tried using some of my existing code to target a B2C tenant and hit this error. @AllenWu do you have a link available for the correct user voice?

Comment: @MattSanders Not sure why https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/ is not available currently.

Comment: Feedback location has moved to: https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback

Answer (score 1):

This should work for a B2C Tenant , using [Connect-AzureAD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/connect-azuread?view=azureadps-2.0) in the [AzureAD Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/?view=azureadps-2.0)

Connect-AzureAD -tenant xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx

(Get-AzureADUser -all $true).Count

Comment: Heh, do that on a 1,000,000+ tenant and get back to me :D

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit manual, but whenever I need a quick count, I do the following:

- Go to Azure Portal (for B2C Tenant)
- All Users
- Bulk operations
- Download users (This will get me an excel pretty quick)
- Start
- Takes about 2 minutes to finish (~40k users)
- Go to Bulk operation results in page menu on the left
- Download Excel
- sum of UPNs in the excel